# mysql/c++ connector error: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused

Tags: c++, mysql, database

So I am a newbie for C++/Mysql and I am sorry if I ask something stupid.

I have encountered the error for connecting mysql from c++

```
SQLException: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)
```

I read many existing solutions for this problem and they seem to suggest restarting the server with some updated settings. However, I am trying to connect to a remote server, and I do not have the root access to that server.

Here are some more details on my server, client and connector:

1. The server version is 5.5.32
2. The client version is  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1. It is strange since this is newer than 4.1.1
3. I also installed MYSQL/C++ Connector 1.1 . I downloaded its source code and built it using CMake without error.

I guess that a simple fix would be to disable "secure_auth" from the connector. However, I don't know how to do this. Is there some parameters that I can pass from my C++ code?

So does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by using [Connector/C++ Connection Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html).

```
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con
driver = get_driver_instance();
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connectionProperties;

connectionProperties["hostName"] = sql::SQLString("tcp://192.168.0.10:3306");
connectionProperties["userName"] = sql::SQLString("root");
connectionProperties["password"] = sql::SQLString("password");
connectionProperties["useLegacyAuth"] = true;
con = driver->connect(connectionProperties);
```

Make sure you have `connectionProperties["useLegacyAuth"] = true;` and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pre 4.1.1 refers to the password you're trying to authenticate against.  If you can't change that to use the more modern (longer) scheme, you can try

1. Using an older client that doesn't have secure_auth enabled by default,
2. Finding where to pass skip_secure_auth (may or may not work), or
3. Patch your client with the one-line fix at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75425 so that secure_auth=FALSE works

Options 2 and 3 are easy if you can use a .cnf file to connect.